# Communicate with C program using stdin/out from Java

Tags: java, c, stdout, stdin

I want my Java program to communicate with a C program. This is just a simple example but I can't get it working. The Java program is supposed to run the C program and write to its input stream. The C program should see this and write to stdout in response. Finally, the Java program should read this response from the C program's stdout and print it to the screen.

Running the C program from command line I get the desired behaviour. However, when ran from the Java program, it just "hangs" and doesn't do anything. The Java program seems to have written its message to C program's stdin, but this message isn't seen in the C program.

I set the C program to write the message it reads to file just to check that it does read the message, and it doesn't do that.

Here is the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void hello();
void wrong();

int main() {
    char buff[256];

    /* 1. read stdin */
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", buff);

    /* side effect - if message was received it should be 
        printed to file */
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", buff);
    fclose(fp);

    /* 2. depending on message, write something to stdout */
    if(strcmp(buff, "hello") == 0) {
        hello();
    } else {
        wrong();
    }
}

void hello() {
    printf("Hello World!");
}

void wrong() {
    printf("WRONG!");
}
```

And here's the Java program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // 1. run C program
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./hello");
            InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = proc.getOutputStream();
            // 2. write 'hello' to 'hello' program
            writeToProc(out, "hello");
            // 3. read response
            readFromProc(in);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // write message to process
    public static void writeToProc(OutputStream out, String msg) throws IOException {
        byte[] buff = msg.getBytes();
        out.write(buff);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("done writing: " + new String(buff));
    }

    // read stdin of process
    public static void readFromProc(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte[] buff = new byte[256];
        int read = in.read();
        for(int i=0; read != -1; i++) {
            read = in.read();
            buff[i] = (byte) read;
        }
        String str = new String(buff);
        System.out.println("proc says: " + str);
    }
}
```

When I run Main, I get the following output:

```
$ java Main
  done writing: hello
```

And then just a blinking cursor and file "file.txt" is not written, indicating that the C program didn't read "hello" from stdin.

This is a simple example so I guess I'm missing something simple or coming at this the wrong way somehow.

Comment: First of all: is the problem with the C program or the Java program?  Then get rid of the tag and the code for the one that's working.

Comment: I don't know. I'm guessing the Java program but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, let's start with this: given that the Java program is calling the C program, does the C program work?

Comment: Yeah. When I just run the C program from command line it runs fine. "file.txt" is written and then the correct message gets printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to add the new line character `\n` to the string that you are sending from Java thus `fscanf` keeps waiting indefinitely for the process to `"press enter"`. I've made some modifications to the code and the changes are documented in comments.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // 1. run C program
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./hello");
            InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = proc.getOutputStream();
            // 2. write 'hello' to 'hello' program
            // <change>
            // don't forget to add the new line here or in the 
            // writeToProc method
            writeToProc(out, "hello\n");
            // 3. read response
            readFromProc(in);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // write message to process
    public static void writeToProc(OutputStream out, String msg) throws IOException {
        // <change>
        // Using UTF-8 encoding since all chars in C are byte sized
        byte[] buff = msg.getBytes("UTF-8");
        out.write(buff);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("done writing: " + new String(buff));
    }

    // read stdin of process
    public static void readFromProc(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte[] buff = new byte[256];
        int read = in.read();
        int index = 0;
        while(read != -1) {
            buff[index] = (byte) read;
            read = in.read();
            ++index;
        }
        String str = new String(buff, 0, index);
        System.out.println("proc says: " + str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the array copy if you use `new String(buff,0,index)` to convert only the valid part of the buffer. (Also the leftover elements contain the `byte` value 0 which is invisible when displayed, not `char '0'` which in ASCII compatible codes including Unicode is 0x30 aka 48.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for your input, I didn't think of the `new String(buff,0,index) ` constructor. Regarding the trailing zeroes, I thought they would be invisible as well but they showed up in eclipse, I do think that they might not show up in a "real" console though but didn't try it. I liked the `new String(buff,0,index)` solution and updated my answer to use that approach. Thanks!